# HttpSession session=request.getSession(false); ruturning null

Tags: session, servlets

my code is

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);

    if(session==null){

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
    }else{

        doPost(request,response);
    }

}
```

the url pattern for this servlet is /loginServlet.
i wrote this code so that if user is logged in and makes a get request by hitting enter on the url then the request must be forwarded to doPost()
or else if the user is not logged in then he get to the login page

but the problem is that its always returning to the login page that means request.getSession(false) always returning null

how can i solve this problem

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String commun=request.getParameter("commun");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
      Connection conn = null;
      Statement  statement = null;


    try{
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/community");
     conn = ds.getConnection();

      statement = conn.createStatement();
      String sql = "select memberragas from windowragas where memberragas='"+name+"' and liquid_key='"+commun+"' and chabhiragas='"+password+"'";
      ResultSet rs =statement.executeQuery(sql);
     if(rs.next()){
         System.out.println("welcome "+name+"");
         HttpSession session=request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute("name", name);
         session.setAttribute("commun", commun);
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/homey");
         rd.forward(request, response);


     }else{
         System.out.println("either ur username or password or community was wrong");
         response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
     }
    }
 catch (NamingException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}finally {

    try {
       if (statement != null) statement.close();
       if (conn != null) conn.close();  // return to pool
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

in the doPost() i m creating the session for the first time

Comment: above code will never create a session. try `request.getSession(true);` which will create a new session if session does not exist, else if it is already created it will return that session object

Comment: @Amit.rk3 sir ,i don't want to create a session , i just want to know that if there is a session already or not

Comment: if its there i want to send the request to the doPost() ,n if there is no session attached then it must go to the login page

Comment: How are you creating the new session when the user logs in? Are you sure the session gets created when you try to create one?

Comment: @user3443275 can you post the code when you create the session?

Comment: @morbidCode sir , i edited my question u can see that i m creating the session inside if(rs.next)

Comment: @user3443275
 are you seeing the welcome output in the console when the user logs in?

Comment: @morbidCode yes sir i m seeing the welcome output in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that when you call `doPost()` directly from your `doGet()` method, the request parameters `name`, `commun` and `password` are not available. Hence, the authenticating SQL query fails and your `else` block executes.

```
 } else {
     System.out.println("either ur username or password or community was wrong");
     response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
 }
```

This is effectively the same as your `doGet()`'s `if` block and hence gives an impression that your `session` is `null`.

```
if (session == null) {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
}
```

So to fix the issue, if the `session` exists, redirect the user immediately instead of trying to execute `doPost()` to authenticate them again. The presence of `name` attribute can further assure that the user has been authenticated before.

```
if (session != null && session.getAttribute("name") != null) {
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/homey");
    rd.forward(request, response);
} else {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
}
```

Comment: Glad to know it helped.