# request.getSession(true) consistently generates a null session

Tags: jsf, httpsession

request.getSession(true) consistently generates a null session. This is across the multitude of Servers- Glassfish 5 and Payara 5. This is such a simple piece of code that we have always taken for granted ever since Java Servlets have existed.

BEFORE ANYONE MARKS MY QUESTION AS 'DUPLICATE' - PLEASE READ BELOW:

This issue has been address in the following post to an extent but still does not answer the question.
[HttpSession session=request.getSession(false); ruturning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046303/httpsession-session-request-getsessionfalse-ruturning-null)

Comment: So it works fine on wildfly 13?

Comment: The question you refer to has an accepted answer. You don't post any new code, so please read [ask] and explain (with code) why your question is different, the other does not help etc. Otherwise I see no reason to **not** mark it as a duplicate. (Using 2 'stars `**bold**` around text, makes it bold. Better instead of 'shouting' usimg capitals.) And payarra and glassfish are 'identical', you do know that?

Comment: @Kukeltje. Appreciate your reply. Yes, I did try wildfly (13 and 14) and yes I am indeed aware that payarra and Glassfish are identical. However the issue got resolved by itself when I used Apache Tomee. It would say it is all sorted now.

Comment: Weird that you select your java-ee server based on this one issue.